# Make x-editable fields appear and trigger onfocus

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I use x-editable for bootstrap to make editable table fields with client data. The problem I have is that I have a field for comments that is sometimes several hundred characters long which makes the table looks hideous since I have to us whitespace:nowrap.

To get around that I used jQuery to show only a section of the comment in the  and hide the editable field when the page loads but to expand when I hover over it. The problem I have is that all the other fields are selectable onfocus with x-editable and I would like to make this field selectable as well. If I hover over the field I can Tab into it without any problem, but I'm interested how I can Tab into the  and trigger the editable field.

The other solution would be that I limit the number of characters php outputs or hide them with jQuery and expand the field when I Tab into it, but I don't know how to do that. I tried looking into :focus and document.activeElement() but didn't find a way to get them work.

I added the sample code to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HRqeJ/1/). I added an input field before the  because when you Tab through the table x-editable makes fields into input elements. If the editable field is active than I can Tab into, but if it isn't the field is skipped and doesn't trigger.

This is a sample of  that holds the editable field

```
<td id="comment" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
    <p id="short_comment">Short comment</p>
    <p id="collapse"><a href="#" id="editable">A much longer comment that will appear</a></p>
</td>
```

This is a sample of jQuery

```
$('#collapse').hide();
$('#comment').on('mouseenter', function(f) {

    $('#short_comment').hide();
    $('#collapse').show();

    $("#collapse").on("show",function(event){
        $('#comment').width('200px');
    });

    $("#collapse").on("hide",function(event){
        $('#comment').width('50px');
    });
});

$('#comment').on('mouseleave', function(f) {
    $('#short_comment').show();
    $('#collapse').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [tabindexes](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H4.html) for your HTML to controll the tabflow:

   ```
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td><input type="text" tabindex='1' /></td>
       <td id="comment" tabindex='2'>
           <p id="short_comment">Short comment</p>
           <p id="collapse"><a href="#" id="editable">A much longer comment that will appear</a></p>
        </td>
       </tr>
   </table>
   ```
2. Add some CSS:

   ```
   #comment:hover #collapse, 
   #comment:focus #collapse {
       display:block;
   }
   #comment #collapse, 
   #comment:hover #short_comment, 
   #comment:focus #short_comment {
       display:none;
   }
   ```
3. Remove the Javascript

Demo: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/HRqeJ/3/)